# unfortunately camera has stopped android emulator

Tags: android

> I am just trying to launch camera from my android emulator and I am getting the above error 
>   unfortunately camera has stopped android  emulator and it stopped
>
> My Android Version 4.0.3 and API 15
>
> My Logs are below ,I have already gone through the other posts in stack overflow related to this but no luck

```
    08-15 18:55:53.361: E/EmulatedCamera_QemuClient(38): queryFrame: Query failed: Unable to obtain video frame from the camera
08-15 18:55:53.361: E/EmulatedCamera_QemuDevice(38): inWorkerThread: Unable to get current video frame: Invalid argument
08-15 18:55:53.401: I/dalvikvm(472): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-15 18:55:53.561: E/Camera(472): Error 100
08-15 18:55:53.561: E/CameraErrorCallback(472): Got camera error callback. error=100
08-15 18:55:53.571: D/AndroidRuntime(472): Shutting down VM
08-15 18:55:53.571: W/dalvikvm(472): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
08-15 18:55:53.591: E/AndroidRuntime(472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 18:55:53.591: E/AndroidRuntime(472): java.lang.RuntimeException: Media server died.
08-15 18:55:53.591: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at com.android.camera.CameraErrorCallback.onError(CameraErrorCallback.java:31)
08-15 18:55:53.591: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:736)
08-15 18:55:53.591: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-15 18:55:53.591: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-15 18:55:53.591: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-15 18:55:53.591: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 18:55:53.591: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-15 18:55:53.591: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-15 18:55:53.591: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-15 18:55:53.591: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-15 18:55:53.621: W/ActivityManager(92):   Force finishing activity com.android.camera/.Camera
08-15 18:55:53.631: W/WindowManager(92): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21015
08-15 18:55:53.811: I/Process(92): Sending signal. PID: 472 SIG: 3
08-15 18:55:53.811: I/dalvikvm(472): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
```

Comment: Post the code you used to create the camera activity. Also, accept some answers to your questions.

Comment: @dmon I am just launching native camera APP not through any application just to test it .. Actually first I tried to run the API Demo app it has no response then i tried to run the camera from the main menu but it always stooped as above